# programming methodology needed, finding irregular/abnormal pattern on image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

I've got 65 heart rate images like below.

I want to distinguish irregular/abnormal heart beat pattern(**red points**) from good ones(**green poins**) on graph in the pictures.

I annotate colorful points along the graph at the moment for question but real images are not annotated.

I thought about deep-learning way but there are only few images(more research needed topics like few-shot learning though)

Therefore, I want to solve this problem algorithmically using image processing.

I can't come up with any good ideas.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you define this irregularity/abnormality if you want to do it algorithmically? I find it difficult to see what's what.

Comment: @dhanushka 
There are ways to differentiate.
One is the distance between lines. the distance between green lines is almost same but you can find the red line appear among those.
Another is line's morphology. If you see graph right before the red one, the bigger mountain appears than the green one's.

However, These characteristics don't appear in some images and are hard to find even in human's eyes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If you can obtain the time domain signal from the image, then, may be you can apply some filters to find those irregularities, or the standard techniques that are used for detecting them. To obtain the signal, you can try segmenting your image based on color, or just crop what's inside the plot box and threshold it. Or do it manually for now and create the 1D signal, then experiment with some filters.

Comment: @dhanushka Thank you for reply. I can't get it what you explain though.. Could you elaborate your way??